# How low can the scale of cosmological inflation be?

Tags: cosmology, higgs, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

Usually, when we think of inflation we think of it happening at high energy scales, close to the bound set by CMB polarization measurements (with a Hubble scale of $H_I\sim 10^{14}$ GeV). However, many times in the literature we encounter low-scale inflation models where $H\sim 10^{-24}$ GeV, corresponding to $T\sim 10$ MeV (so just above the BBN energy scale). In general, people talk about how inflation cannot happen lower than BBN in order not to destroy the element abundancies. However, I haven't found any discussion about whether such low inflationary scales would interfere with other cosmological processes expected to happpen before BBN. For example, can the EWSB happen normally in a background that is expanding in an accelerated manner (in general when we study the Higgs mechanism we don't use the metric in a curved background but we instead use the Minkowski metric). Would the inflaton be detectable by collider experiments if the scale of inflation was so low? Also, since radiation is only produced after or (in some models) during inflation would the fact that the Universe is empty until very late have an impact on other processes that we expect to be happening earlier on and involve particle interactions (thermal leptogenesis comes to mind)?